# I want to import API functions like SOAP UI does, where to start?

Tags: rest, api, soap, service, import

I want to import REST or SOAP services through the URL like SOAP UI does.
Fill in the URL, and return a list of functions + the variables that need to be sent with it. I have no idea what this process is referred to as, so googling is not getting me anywhere. Any tips on where to start?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the answer I was looking for was WSDL.
The WSDL contains all info about a web service and its functions.